# Adding a line to the SSRS field

Tags: replace, line, ssrs-2008

I have a field with a very long value and I have to add a line break at some point on SSRS. I inserted a symbol at that point using T-SQL and then tried to replace that symbol with vbcrlf, char(10), char(13) through SSRS using the Replace function like this

> > =iif(Parameters!Comments.Value = "Yes", Replace(Fields!Addedcomments.Value, "|", vbcrlf), Nothing)

But nothing happens.. it even stops showing that field completely.. I'm confused.. please help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using System.Environment.NewLine

```
="First Line" + System.Environment.NewLine + "Second Line"
```

Comment: Well, I don't have 2 seperate lines.. its a single field value and I have to seperate it as 2 lines at one point..

Comment: Avinash I just gave you an example of how to use a line break in SSRS. Instead of using char(10), char(13) you can use this line break.